# Discrete Least Mean Squared / Least Means Regresssion for multiple samples

Tags: least-squares

I understand how to perform a least means regression of a given set of $x$ points to approximate a line that best fits them. In this case I observe a set of $x$ inputs and y corresponding outputs. Then I can create$ a \hat y = m\hat x+ b$ which is a line that best fits the $x$ and $y$ I observed.

Now let's suppose that I do this experiment several times. Now I have a matrix of $X $observations and a matrix of Y corresponding outputs. How would I find the $\hat y = m\hat x+ b$ that best fits all observations?

Comment: You have a long list of x values and a long list of y values.

Comment: The general case of linear regression is that of projection. Given $X,$ you consider $V$ the image space of $X$ (i.e. "column space") and $P_X$ the orthogonal projector onto $V.$ The multiple linear regression is then $P_X(Y).$

Comment: Please use `\hat x` for $\hat x$ otherwise it looks like exponentiation